# How to break while loop when a new message arrives?

Tags: python, sockets, esp8266

I have used Python socket in `ESP as a server` and `Laptop as a client`. I customized the socket codes from [this site](http://thezanshow.com/electronics-tutorials/raspberry-pi/tutorial-27-28-29). When I send the `loop` as the client input, I enter a loop on the server. I don't know how the `while loop` is broken when I send a word other than `loop`, For example "Hello".

server.py:

```
import socket

host = ''
port = 5560

def setupServer():
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    print("Socket created.")
    try:
        s.bind((host, port))
    except socket.error as msg:
        print(msg)
    print("Socket bind comlete.")
    return s

def setupConnection():
    s.listen(1)
    conn, address = s.accept()
    print("Connected to: " + address[0] + ":" + str(address[1]))
    return conn

def Hello_():
    print('Hello')

def Loop_():
    while True:
        print('yes')
        
def dataTransfer(conn):
    while True:
        data = conn.recv(1024) 
        data = data.decode('utf-8')
        dataMessage = data.split(' ', 1)
        command = dataMessage[0]

        if command == 'loop':
            Loop_()
        if command == 'Hello':
            Hello_()         
        else:
            print("X")

    conn.close()

s = setupServer()

while True:
    try:
        conn = setupConnection()
        dataTransfer(conn)
    except:
        break
```

client.py

```
import socket

host = '192.168.56.1'
port = 5560

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((host, port))

while True:
    command = input("Enter your command: ")
    s.send(str.encode(command))
    
s.close()
```

I know your time is valuable and I appreciate your attention for spending time for help me.

Comment: How do you mean "broken"? Once the server has printed the response to the "Hello" command (that is, has printed "Hello"), it simply waits for the next command. Only when you enter "loop" as command, the server gets into an infinite loop, blocking all communications with clients.

Comment: @00 I want the `Loop_()` method to return when more message is received on the socket.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the `Loop_()` method to return when more data is received on the socket, you can modify the method so that it calls `select()` to poll the socket to see if more data has arrived, as shown below.  (Note that I've added a `conn` argument to the `Loop_()` method so I can pass in the socket to check it)

```py
import select

[...]

def Loop_(conn):
    while True:
        print('yes')
        inReady, outReady, exReady = select.select([conn], [], [], 0.0)
        if (conn in inReady):
           print('more data has arrived at the TCP socket, returning from Loop_()')
           break

def dataTransfer(conn):
    while True:
        data = conn.recv(1024)
        data = data.decode('utf-8')
        dataMessage = data.split(' ', 1)
        command = dataMessage[0]

        if command == 'loop':
            Loop_(conn)
        if command == 'Hello':
            Hello_()
        else:
            print("X")

    conn.close()
```

Comment: Thanks, I needed exactly that, but now when I send the `loop`, it prints `yes` and exits the program.

Comment: Don’t forget to add the ‘import select’ line to the top of the script

Comment: Note that the `except:  break` clause at the end of your script is swallowing up any error messages so that you can't see them when something goes wrong.  You probably want to at least print out the exception when you catch it, so you can see what happened.